# DeleteDuplicates With Negative Entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm working now with xAct in Mathematica obtaining huge list  of contractions of a metric tensor with vector fields. When making contractions with the Levi-Civita tensor, I realized that there are terms in which the only difference is a negative sign. Since they are at the Lagrangians, the negative sign does not matter. The question is: there is any option in DeleteDuplicates (or perhaps any other command) to force eliminate terms which only differs in a sign?. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like this?  `DeleteDuplicates[expr, #1 === -#2 &]`. The problem is that if the two expression don't have the same structure, it might not work. Maybe wrapping the `Slot`s in `Simplify` would do the trick.

Comment: For instance, this doesn't work: `DeleteDuplicates[{1/(b - a), -1/(a - b)}, #1 === -#2 &]`.

Comment: Hi @march the example works, since $-1/(a-b) =1/(b-a)$, so it does not delete it.

Answer (score 2):

A refinement (IMO) of David's code:

```
expressionlist = {
  2 + 4 x^2,
  2 (1 + 2 x^2),
  -(x + 1)^2,
  x^2 + 2 x + 1, 
  Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2,
  1
};

DeleteDuplicates[Simplify@expressionlist, FullSimplify[# == #2 || -# == #2] &]
```

> ```
> {2 + 4 x^2, -(1 + x)^2, 1}
> ```

Also try `FullSimplify[Abs[#] == Abs[#2]] &`

Comment: Oh...silly me...of course!!..taking absolute values would give a short way to that!.

Answer (score 1):

```
FullSimplify /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates[
     expressionlist, 
    (FullSimplify[#1] === FullSimplify[#2] || 
     FullSimplify[#1] === -FullSimplify[#2] ) &]
```

Example:

```
expressionlist = {
   2 + 4 x^2, 2 (1 + 2 x^2), 
   -(x + 1)^2, x^2 + 2 x + 1, 
   Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2, 1};
```

(* {2 + 4 x^2, -(1 + x)^2, 1} *)